# New function doesn't accept returned values from other function

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, csv

I'm reading from a CSV file and created a function that separates the players from that file into 2 lists: experienced and fresh players.

Then, I tried to create another function that would print the length of each list. However, when I run my script and I call for the 2 functions, Python returns an error saying that the variables of the second function are not defined. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
import csv

with open('soccer_players.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    players_reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    players = list(players_reader)

def separate(players):
    experienced = []
    fresh = []
    for player in players:
        if player['Soccer Experience'] == 'YES':
            experienced.append(player)
        else:
            fresh.append(player)

    return experienced, fresh


def countexperience (experienced, fresh):
    players_experience = len(experienced)
    players_fresh = len(fresh)

    print(players_experience)
    print(players_fresh)

while True:
    start = input("Want to start? (Y/n) ").lower()
    if start == "y":
        separate(players)
        countexperience(experienced, fresh)
        break
    elif start == "n":
        print("goodbye")
        break
    else:
        print("letter not accepted! Please write 'Y' to start or 'N' to exit!\n")
```

Result:

```
countexperience(experienced, fresh)
NameError: name 'experienced' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local variables in `separate()` are not added to the current scope, so you need to assign the return of `separate()` to variables in the current scope, e.g.:

```
experienced, fresh = separate(players)
```

Note: you can use any names you want, e.g.

```
e, f = separate(players)
countexperience(e, f)
```

You can also expand the `tuple` return from `separate()` directly in the function call to `countexperience()` using `*`, e.g.:

```
countexperience(*separate(players))
```